# Correct way to bind classNames with useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to fetch data from cookie using useSelector from redux-toolkit.

When I log the fetched data value to console, it shows the correct value which is true, however when I try to bind that value as className it refers as undefined.

I assume that data fetching is asynchronous way so that it renders undefined?

```
const Layout = ({children, title}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const darkMode = useSelector(getDarkMode);
    const classes = useStlyes();

    console.log(darkMode); // true

    const clickHandler = () => {
        dispatch(setDarkMode(!darkMode));
        Cookies.set('darkMode',!darkMode);
    }


    return (
        <div className={classNames(darkMode ?? 'null or undefined')}>
        </div>)
})
```

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'user',
    initialState : {
        darkMode : Cookies.get('darkMode')
    },
    reducers : {
        setDarkMode : (state, {payload}) => {
            state.darkMode = payload;
        }
    }
})
```

How do I fix that and bind correct className?

[component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZkZJ.png)

[redux-toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B74pG.png)

Comment: Please share code as properly formatted and readable code snippets instead of images. Images are not searchable or copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult to read. So far all the code I see to get the `darkMode` is synchronous. The only asynchronous code I saw was the `clickHandler`. You *are* console logging as an unintentional side-effect in the body of the function component though. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese
Hi,
Then how do I bind the value of darkMode to className inside the div?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you mean by "bind" to className, you pull the value from state via the selector and pass it as the value of `className` prop. What isn't working? Can you provide more detail? Is the `clickHandler` not toggling the value in state? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese

`console.log(darMode) // prints **true**

return (
        <div className={classNames(darkMode ?? 'null or undefined')}>
        </div>
)

// className is undefined so that <div> has className **'null or undefined'** instead of **true**

I want to add **ture** as className inside of <div> Not **null or undefined**`

Comment: So I'm guessing that `true` is the initial `darkMode` value in your redux state. Do you see it toggle when clicking the button? Also, I'm not sure boolean values are valid CSS class names, you may need to stringify it or pass a value that is a string.

Comment: @DrewReese
I don't know what happened but when I check redux devtool it shows `true` is the initial `darkMode` value but I found that it actually has `undefined`. When I change initial state to `darkMode: Cookies.get('darkMode') ?? 'WHAT'` <div> has the className `WHAT` but devtool shows `true`......

Comment: Interesting. Think you could standup a *running* codesandbox of your code so that we could inspect and debug it live? Or have this code hosted in a public repo/github?

Comment: What is `getDarkMode` and does it actually reference the correct path in the store?